# dataframe transform partial row data on column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have one dataframe where format is given as below image.
Every row where three columns are representing as one type of data. In given example there are one column for ticker and next three column is kind one type of data and column 5-7are second type of data.
Now I want to transform this in column where every type of data appended by another group.

[image]

Expected output is:

[image]

is there anyway to do this transformation in pandas using any API? I am doing it very basic way where creating a new dataframe for one group and then appending it.

Comment: Please add text representation of the DataFrame

Comment: posted a solution. does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

use pd.melt to unstack the table, then split what used to be columns (and now as rows) on "/" to separate them into two columns (txt, year)

create the new row value by combining ticker and year, then using pivot to get the desired result set

```
df2=df.melt(id_vars='ticker', var_name='col') # line missed in earlier solution,updated
df2[['txt','year']] = df.melt(id_vars='ticker', var_name='col')['col'].str.split('/', expand=True)
df2.assign(ticker2=df2['ticker'] + '/' + df2['year']).pivot(index='ticker2', columns='txt', values='value').reset_index()
```

Result set

```
txt     ticker2     data1   data2
0   AAPL/2020   0.824676    0.616524
1   AAPL/2021   0.018540    0.046365
2   AAPL/2022   0.222349    0.729845
3   AMZ/2020    0.122288    0.087217
4   AMZ/2021    0.012168    0.734674
5   AMZ/2022    0.923501    0.437676
6   APPL/2020   0.886927    0.520650
7   APPL/2021   0.725515    0.543404
8   APPL/2022   0.211378    0.464898
9   GGL/2020    0.777676    0.052658
10  GGL/2021    0.297292    0.213876
11  GGL/2022    0.894150    0.185207
12  MICO/2020   0.898251    0.882252
13  MICO/2021   0.141342    0.105316
14  MICO/2022   0.440459    0.811005
```

based on the code that you posted in comment. I missed a line, unfortunately, in posting the solution. its added now

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2, 6)), 
                                     columns=["data1/2020","data1/2021", "data1/2022", "data2/2020", "data2/2021", "data2/2022"]) 
ticker = ['APPL', 'MICO'] 
df2.insert(loc=0, column='ticker', value=ticker) 
df2.head() 

df3=df2.melt(id_vars='ticker', var_name='col') # missed line in earlier posting
df3[['txt','year']] = df2.melt(id_vars='ticker', var_name='col')['col'].str.split('/', expand=True) 
df3.head() 
df3.assign(ticker2=df3['ticker'] + '/' + df3['year']).pivot(index='ticker2', columns='txt', values='value').reset_index()
```

```
txt     ticker2       data1     data2
0       APPL/2020       26      9
1       APPL/2021       75      59
2       APPL/2022       20      44
3       MICO/2020       79      90
4       MICO/2021       63      30
5       MICO/2022       73      91
```

Comment: code is giving compilations error.

Comment: @CrazyC, can you post details of the error? I applied the solution on the dataset that you shared (as an image) and shared the result.

Comment: KeyError: 'value'
```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2, 6)), columns=["data1/2020","data1/2021", "data1/2022", "data2/2020", "data2/2021", "data2/2022"])
ticker = ['APPL', 'MICO']
df2.insert(loc=0, column='ticker', value=ticker)
df2.head()
df2[['txt','year']] = df2.melt(id_vars='ticker', var_name='col')['col'].str.split('/', expand=True)
df2.head()
df2.assign(ticker2=df2['ticker'] + '/' + df2['year']).pivot(index='ticker2', columns='txt', values='value').reset_index()
```

Comment: @CrazyC, i missed a line in my solution. I just updated the solution and also executed it based on the data your shared. a new DF (df3), is created using pd.melt from df2, and all computation is based off of it. Hope it helps

Comment: @CrazyC, do advise on how it goes. Thanks!